# Infinite scrolling is updating all my observables in Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Is there a way to keep my last posts from the first call to not being overwritten by the next call of the same function?

In other words , I have an API route like this:

```
{{url}}?/page=1&limit=3

// page represents a param that i can manipulate incoming posts;
// limit represents how many posts will show with the call;
```

This route returns me 3 posts , but after I change `page=2`
I get the next 3 posts from all posts and my previous posts gets overwritten..

**UPDATED AGAIN**

//this is the service for getting posts;

```
allPosts$;
isLastPage = false;
currentPage = 0;
pageNumberSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);
pageSizeAction$ = this.pageNumberSubject.asObservable();

 getSimplePosts(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.pageSizeAction$.pipe(
      concatMap((pgNum: number): Observable<SimplePosts[]> =>
        this.http.get<SimplePosts[]>(this._allPostsAPI, {
          params: {
            page: pgNum.toString(),
            limit: "3"
          }
        })
      ),
scan((allPosts: SimplePosts[], pageUsers: SimplePosts[]) => [...allPosts, pageUsers], []),
tap((posts: SimplePosts[]) => console.log(JSON.stringify(posts))))

  }


  nextPage() {
    this.currentPage += 1;
    this.pageNumberSubject.next(this.currentPage);
  }


// old implementation;
getAllPosts(page, limit) {
  return this.http.get(`${this._allPostsAPI}?page=${page}&limit=${limit}`, httpOptions);
}
```

**How can I use it in my component ??**
I can't implement the function right in my component because I have tokens bypass and they get along in service..

This is very hard really.. i spent so many hours trying to figure out , but its too challenging for me right now..
I will rollback everything for now. If I will find a way to do this I will sure update this for everyone that needs it.

//this is the component where I use the infinite scroll;

```
  personSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  person$: Observable<any> = this.personSubject.asObservable();
  private destroy$ = new Subject();


  constructor(){

//first initialise posts as first page ,
//then after the user scrolls down it activates the doInfinite() function; 

this.authService.getSimplePosts().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
.subscribe((res: any) => {
console.log(res);

res.map((simplePosts: any) => {
console.log(simplePosts);
this.personSubject.next(simplePosts.data.post);

this.userGallery = simplePosts.data.post.forEach(imgIndex => {
imgIndex.galleryImages = imgIndex.images.map((image: any, index: number) => {
            return new Image(
              index,
              { //modal
                img: image,
                extUrl: image,
                title: image,

              },
            )

          });

        });
      });

    })

}
  
 doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {

setTimeout(() => {
console.log(this.allPosts$);

//here i call the function and it works , but my observables are still gone :D
this.authService.nextPage();

this.authService.getSimplePosts().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$), share()).subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
res.map((simplePosts: any) => {
console.log(simplePosts);
this.personSubject.next(simplePosts.data.post);
this.userGallery = simplePosts.data.post.forEach(imgIndex => {
imgIndex.galleryImages = imgIndex.images.map((image: any, index: number) => {
              return new Image(
                index,
                { //modal
                  img: image,
                  extUrl: image,
                  title: image,

                },
              )
            });

          });
        });
      })

      console.log(infiniteScroll)
      infiniteScroll.target.complete();
    }, 1000);

  }
```

** EDITED; **
This is the final stage , I did as your stackblitz , but after i scroll down , my observables gets overwritted and the page doesnt concatenate , it calls the same page again. Help?!

[image]

Comment: Remove the code from within the constructor. It should be declared as a variable as shown in my example. Also, you can't console.log after it as you have. Instead, it should be a `tap()` operator. (the http call is async so you can't console.log it except within the pipeline with a `tap`.) When I have a few free moments, I'll update the stackblitz example to move the code into a service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `scan()` and add the newly retrieved items to an array of retained items. You'd need to be careful though because if you are re-retrieving as the user navigates around in the application, you could end up with duplicate information in that retained array.

UPDATE:
The following demonstrates how to use the `scan` operator with paging.

NOTE: This makes the assumption that pages are advanced sequentially with no going backwards or skipping pages.

```
  allPosts$ = this.pageSizeAction$.pipe(
    concatMap(page =>
      this.http.get<Post[]>(this.postUrl, {
        params: {
          _page: page.toString(),
          _limit: "2"
        }
      })
    ),
    scan((acc, value) => [...acc, ...value])
  );
```

The scan takes in the accumulated value (`acc`), which starts with the first set of retrieved data by default. And it takes in the newly retrieved value (`value`). So this uses array spread syntax to spread the values of each array (the original and the newly retrieved set) into a new array.

You can find a working stackblitz here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-paging-api-deborahk

Comment: How can I use it ? If i recall the function with new params (page=2) for example , all the posts from the first page gets disposed and shows me only those from page 2 , i want that my observable to not get destroyed .. I think I want too much right? xd

Comment: No, not asking too much. I frequently use `scan()` to retain the full set of items when allowing create, update, and delete operations. Problem I have in trying to provide a code example is that I don't know of a public API that provides paging. Do you? Or can you provide a *short*, *working* example of what you are trying to accomplish using Stackblitz?

Comment: I found an API that allowed for paging so worked up an example.

Comment: I updated.. but your example is in the component , mine is in service , so i guess this wont work. And more than that I have to call posts first , then after user scrolls 500px it activates some magic tool and call the function again. Its kinda too hard for me, im still a beginner , but I will find a way! Thank you for help

Comment: It's just a quick demo. There is no reason this code couldn't be in a service instead. And you can replace the next button BehaviorSubject with the scroll action. Do you have a Pluralsight membership? They have a couple of good RxJS courses.

Comment: I modified my Stackblitz to move the code into a service and to show the tap for the logging. Hope this helps!

Comment: I updated my question , I did as you did in stackblitz , but now is that problem..

Comment: Try forking the stackblitz and adding your scrolling code so I can see how you've fit it into what I provided.

Comment: I used your forked stackblitz and have it working with the Next button here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-deborahk

Comment: thank you very much! so 2 days ago I asked a senior angular dev and he told me that the mistake was when I tried to feed behavior subject with subscribe and the informations were erased with new one. The best way is to build everything in service and just call the observable.

Comment: if you need to merge them before the observable completes, use mergeMap instead